# SLComposeViewController will crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

A strange bug, I use following code to share some in facebook

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
SLComposeViewController *slComposeViewController = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

[slComposeViewController setInitialText:@"text"];
[slComposeViewController addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"]];
[self presentViewController:slComposeViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
} else {
 NSLog(@"Facebook not available");
}
```

If there's no facebook account under ios setting, and no facebook app, the above code will run well, show the log 'Facebook not available', but if there's no facebook account under ios setting, and has facebook app, the above code will crash. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the FBSDK instead.
[here is the tutorial link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/ios)

```
let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
            content.contentURL = NSURL(string: "http://share.html?id=\(1)&type=0")

            content.contentDescription = "here goes your description"



            content.imageURL = NSURL(string: "\(API_BASE_URL)\(primaryImagepath)")


            dialog.shareContent = content
            if  dialog.canShow() {
                dialog.show()
            }else{
                dialog.mode = .FeedBrowser
                dialog.show()
            }
```